# For which $x\in \mathbb{R}$ does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x^{2n}}{n} - \frac{n^{2x}}{x}\right)$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to study for which values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the following series converges:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x^{2n}}{n} - \frac{n^{2x}}{x}\right)$$

I was only able to say that the necessary condition for the convergence of the series, $\left(\frac{x^{2n}}{n} - \frac{n^{2x}}{x}\right) \to 0$, is satisfied iff $-1<x<0$, but then I'm stuck. How would you complete the problem?

Comment: "necessary condition ... iff " is a weird statement.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What do you mean?

Comment: It makes sense if you read it carefully, but it reads as wrong at first.

Comment: For $\lvert x\rvert < 1$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n}$ is absolutely convergent. So the series you have is convergent if and only if the other part is convergent.

Comment: Ineed, there is a close form for $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n}$$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see what you mean and I've done the calculations, but I must be getting wrong somewhere because I get x>1/2 as a result. Could you convert your comment into an answer and add some details?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What is it? (Also, can you have a look at my comment above?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you found the necessary condition $-1 < x < 0$, it follows that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n}$$

converges (absolutely) for all these values of $x$. Thus for $-1 < x < 0$, the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \biggl(\frac{x^{2n}}{n} - \frac{n^{2x}}{x}\biggr)\tag{1}$$

converges if and only if

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{2x}}{x}$$

converges. The constant factor $\frac{1}{x}$ doesn't influence convergence, so you need to see when

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{2x}$$

converges. It is well-known that that series converges if and only if $2x < -1$, so $x < -\frac{1}{2}$.

Together, we find that the series $(1)$ converges if and only if $-1 < x < -\frac{1}{2}$.

Since

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n} = \log \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{2x} = \zeta(-2x),$$

the sum of the series $(1)$ is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \biggl(\frac{x^{2n}}{n} - \frac{n^{2x}}{x}\biggr) = \log \frac{1}{1-x^2} - \frac{\zeta(-2x)}{x}.$$

Comment: You're perfectly right. Thank you.